# Express-session uses Redis. When Redis stops, the request is blocked

Tags: express, nestjs, express-session

In NestJS, I use Express-Session and use Redis as Store.

The Redis address is a load balancing address. When I offline the Redis server, I sent a new request and found that I had been loading until timeout. I want to return the response after the redis error is detected.

```js
const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
const redisClient = new Redis('redis://****:6379');
redisClient.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.use(
    session({
      store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
      secret: 'asdasdasd',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: { httpOnly: true, maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 10 },
    }),
  );
```

redis error

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/code/nestjs-session/node_modules/ioredis/built/Redis.js:168:41)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:312:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:474:8)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7) {
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try with redis legacy mode

```
const redis = createClient({ socket: { host: "localhost", port: 6379 }, legacyMode: true });
```